# Unable to change theme in primeui

Tags: css, primefaces

I use `primeui` library in my app and want to change the default theme. I followed this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/changing-theme-in-primefaces/) and made my link tag looking like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="primeui/production/primeui-1.1-min.scc?
ln=primefaces-glass-x" />
```

But it has no effect.

Comment: Did you write that href or is it generated for you? It looks rather weird

Comment: are you aware that PrimeUI != PrimeFaces?

Comment: Please see the showcase example, code is also at github, it is one line js call -> primefaces.org/primeui